# Why is this Query statement not displaying "text" formatted phone numbers" on Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, string-formatting, substitution, google-query-language

This formula is returning eveything right,but the phone numbers, which are preceded by an apostrophe. If I happen to delete the apostrophe, it displays the numbers, but since there may be a 0 at the beginning, it has to come as text.

Here's the formula:

```
=iferror(QUERY('Form Responses'!$A$4:$P; "select N, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, A where N >= 1 and todate(A)=date '"&TEXT(B3;"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' order by N Asc");"Pick a date")
```

Here's how the data looks:
[image]

...and this is the result right now:
[image]

Here's the link to an example:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vxCwfcXRrpuvmkhpRsFrKQSq5aMjkdqlUYY-6_UknuE/edit?usp=sharing

Appreciate your time/help - as usual!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(SUBSTITUTE(IFERROR(QUERY(
 {'Form Responses'!A4:P\ TEXT('Form Responses'!E4:E; "\×0")}; 
 "select Col14,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col17,Col6,Col7,Col8,Col9,Col10,Col11,Col12,Col1 
  where Col14 >= 1 
    and todate(Col1) = date '"&TEXT(B3; "yyyy-mm-dd")&"' 
  order by Col14 asc"); "Pick a date"); "×"; ))
```

### update:

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TEXT(SUBSTITUTE(IFERROR(QUERY(
 {'Form Responses'!A4:P\ TEXT('Form Responses'!E4:E; "\×0")}; 
 "select Col14,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col17,Col6,Col7,Col8,Col9,Col10,Col11,Col12,Col1 
  where Col14 >= 1 
    and todate(Col1) = date '"&TEXT(B3; "yyyy-mm-dd")&"' 
  order by Col14 asc"); "Pick a date"); "×"; ); 
 {"@"\"@"\"@"\"@"\"\0#"\"@"\"@"\"@"\"@"\"@"\"@"\"@"\"mm/dd/yyyy"}))
```

[image]

Comment: Right on! That'd take me quite a while to understand why this works...imagine having to figure it out on my own. Thank you!

Comment: Hi again! There's one issue, though. The columns containing dates are now numbers and I can't seem to force their formatting into dates. Would there be a work around? Thanks a lot!

Comment: ...also, the phone numbers are coming without the zeros at the beginning.

Comment: Just added a link to an example. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vxCwfcXRrpuvmkhpRsFrKQSq5aMjkdqlUYY-6_UknuE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @santosOnit answer updated